# WITH keyword is required

Tags: sql, sql-server

While running the following SQL query -

```
INSERT INTO Countries ('sno', 'Name' ) VALUES
(1, 'Afghanistan'),
(2, 'Albania'),
(3, 'Algeria'),
(4, 'American Samoa'),
(5, 'Andorra'),
(6, 'Angola'),
(7, 'Anguilla'),
(8, 'Antarctica'),
(9, 'Antigua and Barbuda'),
(10, 'Argentina'),
(11, 'Armenia'),
(12, 'Armenia'),
(13, 'Aruba'),
(14, 'Australia'),
(15, 'Austria'),
(16, 'Azerbaijan'),
(17, 'Azerbaijan'),
(18, 'Bahamas'),
(19, 'Bahrain'),
(20, 'Bangladesh'),
(21, 'Barbados'),
(22, 'Belarus'),
(23, 'Belgium'),
(24, 'Belize'),
(25, 'Benin'),
(26, 'Bermuda'),
(27, 'Bhutan'),
(28, 'Bolivia'),
(29, 'Bosnia and Herzegovina'),
(30, 'Botswana'),
(31, 'Bouvet Island'),
(32, 'Brazil'),
(33, 'British Indian Ocean Territory'),
(34, 'Brunei Darussalam'),
(35, 'Bulgaria'),
(36, 'Burkina Faso'),
(37, 'Burundi'),
(38, 'Cambodia'),
(39, 'Cameroon'),
(40, 'Canada'),
(41, 'Cape Verde'),
(42, 'Cayman Islands'),
(43, 'Central African Republic'),
(44, 'Chad'),
(45, 'Chile'),
(46, 'China'),
(47, 'Christmas Island'),
(48, 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands'),
(49, 'Colombia'),
(50, 'Comoros'),
(51, 'Congo'),
(52, 'Congo, The Democratic Republic of The'),
(53, 'Cook Islands'),
(54, 'Costa Rica'),
(55, 'Cote Divoire'),
(56, 'Croatia'),
(57, 'Cuba'),
(58, 'Cyprus'),
(59, 'Cyprus'),
(60, 'Czech Republic'),
(61, 'Denmark'),
(62, 'Djibouti'),
(63, 'Dominica'),
(64, 'Dominican Republic'),
(65, 'Easter Island'),
(66, 'Ecuador'),
(67, 'Egypt'),
(68, 'El Salvador'),
(69, 'Equatorial Guinea'),
(70, 'Eritrea'),
(71, 'Estonia'),
(72, 'Ethiopia'),
(73, 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)'),
(74, 'Faroe Islands'),
(75, 'Fiji'),
(76, 'Finland'),
(77, 'France'),
(78, 'French Guiana'),
(79, 'French Polynesia'),
(80, 'French Southern Territories'),
(81, 'Gabon'),
(82, 'Gambia'),
(83, 'Georgia'),
(84, 'Georgia'),
(85, 'Germany'),
(86, 'Ghana'),
(87, 'Gibraltar'),
(88, 'Greece'),
(89, 'Greenland'),
(90, 'Greenland'),
(91, 'Grenada'),
(92, 'Guadeloupe'),
(93, 'Guam'),
(94, 'Guatemala'),
(95, 'Guinea'),
(96, 'Guinea-bissau'),
(97, 'Guyana'),
(98, 'Haiti'),
(99, 'Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands'),
(100, 'Honduras'),
(101, 'Hong Kong'),
(102, 'Hungary'),
(103, 'Iceland'),
(104, 'India'),
(105, 'Indonesia'),
(106, 'Indonesia'),
(107, 'Iran'),
(108, 'Iraq'),
(109, 'Ireland'),
(110, 'Israel'),
(111, 'Italy'),
(112, 'Jamaica'),
(113, 'Japan'),
(114, 'Jordan'),
(115, 'Kazakhstan'),
(116, 'Kazakhstan'),
(117, 'Kenya'),
(118, 'Kiribati'),
(119, 'Korea, North'),
(120, 'Korea, South'),
(121, 'Kosovo'),
(122, 'Kuwait'),
(123, 'Kyrgyzstan'),
(124, 'Laos'),
(125, 'Latvia'),
(126, 'Lebanon'),
(127, 'Lesotho'),
(128, 'Liberia'),
(129, 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya'),
(130, 'Liechtenstein'),
(131, 'Lithuania'),
(132, 'Luxembourg'),
(133, 'Macau'),
(134, 'Macedonia'),
(135, 'Madagascar'),
(136, 'Malawi'),
(137, 'Malaysia'),
(138, 'Maldives'),
(139, 'Mali'),
(140, 'Malta'),
(141, 'Marshall Islands'),
(142, 'Martinique'),
(143, 'Mauritania'),
(144, 'Mauritius'),
(145, 'Mayotte'),
(146, 'Mexico'),
(147, 'Micronesia, Federated States of'),
(148, 'Moldova, Republic of'),
(149, 'Monaco'),
(150, 'Mongolia'),
(151, 'Montenegro'),
(152, 'Montserrat'),
(153, 'Morocco'),
(154, 'Mozambique'),
(155, 'Myanmar'),
(156, 'Namibia'),
(157, 'Nauru'),
(158, 'Nepal'),
(159, 'Netherlands'),
(160, 'Netherlands Antilles'),
(161, 'New Caledonia'),
(162, 'New Zealand'),
(163, 'Nicaragua'),
(164, 'Niger'),
(165, 'Nigeria'),
(166, 'Niue'),
(167, 'Norfolk Island'),
(168, 'Northern Mariana Islands'),
(169, 'Norway'),
(170, 'Oman'),
(171, 'Pakistan'),
(172, 'Palau'),
(173, 'Palestinian Territory'),
(174, 'Panama'),
(175, 'Papua New Guinea'),
(176, 'Paraguay'),
(177, 'Peru'),
(178, 'Philippines'),
(179, 'Pitcairn'),
(180, 'Poland'),
(181, 'Portugal'),
(182, 'Puerto Rico'),
(183, 'Qatar'),
(184, 'Reunion'),
(185, 'Romania'),
(186, 'Russia'),
(187, 'Russia'),
(188, 'Rwanda'),
(189, 'Saint Helena'),
(190, 'Saint Kitts and Nevis'),
(191, 'Saint Lucia'),
(192, 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon'),
(193, 'Saint Vincent and The Grenadines'),
(194, 'Samoa'),
(195, 'San Marino'),
(196, 'Sao Tome and Principe'),
(197, 'Saudi Arabia'),
(198, 'Senegal'),
(199, 'Serbia and Montenegro'),
(200, 'Seychelles'),
(201, 'Sierra Leone'),
(202, 'Singapore'),
(203, 'Slovakia'),
(204, 'Slovenia'),
(205, 'Solomon Islands'),
(206, 'Somalia'),
(207, 'South Africa'),
(208, 'South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands'),
(209, 'Spain'),
(210, 'Sri Lanka'),
(211, 'Sudan'),
(212, 'Suriname'),
(213, 'Svalbard and Jan Mayen'),
(214, 'Swaziland'),
(215, 'Sweden'),
(216, 'Switzerland'),
(217, 'Syria'),
(218, 'Taiwan'),
(219, 'Tajikistan'),
(220, 'Tanzania, United Republic of'),
(221, 'Thailand'),
(222, 'Timor-leste'),
(223, 'Togo'),
(224, 'Tokelau'),
(225, 'Tonga'),
(226, 'Trinidad and Tobago'),
(227, 'Tunisia'),
(228, 'Turkey'),
(229, 'Turkey'),
(230, 'Turkmenistan'),
(231, 'Turks and Caicos Islands'),
(232, 'Tuvalu'),
(233, 'Uganda'),
(234, 'Ukraine'),
(235, 'United Arab Emirates'),
(236, 'United Kingdom'),
(237, 'United States'),
(238, 'United States Minor Outlying Islands'),
(239, 'Uruguay'),
(240, 'Uzbekistan'),
(241, 'Vanuatu'),
(242, 'Vatican City'),
(243, 'Venezuela'),
(244, 'Vietnam'),
(245, 'Virgin Islands, British'),
(246, 'Virgin Islands, U.S.'),
(247, 'Wallis and Futuna'),
(248, 'Western Sahara'),
(249, 'Yemen'),
(250, 'Yemen'),
(251, 'Zambia'),
(252, 'Zimbabwe');
```

following  error code is seen on microsoft sql server-

Msg 215, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Parameters supplied for object 'Countries' which is not a function. If the parameters are intended as a table hint, a WITH keyword is required.

Please help by sharing the reason ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use single quotes for column name.

```
INSERT INTO Countries ([sno], [Name])...
```

You can use brackets normally.
Or you can use double quote `"` if SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON (it should be by default)

Currently you have string literals which is causing SQL Server to interpret the code way different to what you expect

Comment: Actually I personally recommend to *never* use any quoting for identifiers (neither `[]` nor `"`"). If they are needed it means non-standard names (reserved words, special characters) are used which is not a good idea in the long run.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: agree 100%

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - disagree slightly with your comment as the user might like to include a gap in the field name to make things more readable and therefore `[ ]` will be required - I don't think a db designer should be including gaps but a user who just extracts data might like gaps

Comment: +1 @podiluska nice comment ... although some things like MyfavouriteIceCream is never going to be a reserved word so no massive pressure for `[ ]` there

Answer (score 1):

You could leave all the bracketed section out all together: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25deb/1)

```
INSERT INTO Countries VALUES
```

This is therefore none explicit and not best practice (see comment by @AaronBertrand) - but still an alternative.

Comment: This practice is not recommended, mostly because it fixes that query to the current state of the table. If I add, remove or rearrange columns later, this code breaks.